# Removing unwanted characters, and writing from a JSON response

Tags: python, json, api, csv, python-requests

So, I am trying to extract specific data and write it to a file, this JSON response has odd brackets around the information I want and need to be stripped off and I'm not really sure how to get to the 'desired output'.

Maybe its better to do it in an xls document? The end goal is to compare this list against another to find which hosts are missing.

Its a very lengthy response, so I just grabbed a snippet.

The JSON response

```
  [
  {
    "adapter_list_length": 3,
    "adapters": [
      "adapter1",
      "adapter2",
      "adapter3"
    ],
    "id": "",
    "labels": [
      "",
      ""
    ],
    "specific_data.data.hostname": [
      "HOSTNAME1"
    ],
    "specific_data.data.last_seen": "",
    "specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips": [
      "123.45.67.89"
    ],
    "specific_data.data.os.type": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  {
    "adapter_list_length": 3,
    "adapters": [
      "adapter1",
      "adapter2",
      "adapter3"
    ],
    "id": "",
    "labels": [
      "",
      ""
    ],
    "specific_data.data.hostname": [
      "HOSTNAME2"
```

My test writer:

```
names = [item['specific_data.data.hostname'] for item in data]

with open ('namelist.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\n', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow(names)
```

Current output:

```
['HOSTNAME1'] 
['HOSTNAME2']
```

Desired Output:

```
Hostnames:     IPaddress:
HOSTNAME1      123.45.67.89 
HOSTNAME2      123.456.78.9 
....            ....
...             ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it done this way:

```
import csv
data = [{'adapter_list_length': 3, 'adapters': ['adapter1', 'adapter2', 'adapter3'], 
'id': '', 'labels': ['', ''], 'specific_data.data.hostname': ['HOSTNAME1'], 
'specific_data.data.last_seen': '', 'specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips': 
['123.45.67.89'], 'specific_data.data.os.type': ['']}, {'adapter_list_length': 3, 
'adapters': ['adapter1', 'adapter2', 'adapter3'], 'id': '', 'labels': ['', ''], 
'specific_data.data.hostname': ['HOSTNAME2'],'specific_data.data.last_seen': '', 
'specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips': ['123.45.67.80'], 
'specific_data.data.os.type': ['']}]    
names = [item['specific_data.data.hostname'][0] for item in data]
ips = [item['specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips'][0] for item in data]

dets = list(zip(names,ips))
print('Hostnames:','\t','IPaddress:')
for i,j in dets:
    print(i,'\t',j)

fields = ['Hostnames:', 'IPaddress:']      
rows = [list(x) for x in dets]     
filename = "dumb.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:   
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)  
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)   
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: can't use pandas unfortunatly

Comment: You may just have it printed then. I've updated my answer to do this.

Comment: Needs to be written into two separate columns in a CSV though.

Comment: You should be able to handle that by now

Comment: for some reason, the hostnames eventually stop writing their full name, and just put the first letter.

Comment: Kindly provide more of the content of your JSON file, so i can figure what the issue is.